# Check if label value is in the list of possible values for prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I want to check if value for the metric is above threshold for a metric with a specific values in a label. I have a long list of those values (~30), and only those.

```
a_metric_total {alabel="foo"} >= 1
```

alabel can be foo, foobar, bar, (but not `barfoo`, so I don't want to use regexp).

I wanted something like this:

```
a_metric_total {alabel in ["foo", "bar", "foobar"]} >= 1
```

Is there a way to do `in` operation for a label and a set/list of constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to select metrics based on multiple values of label are regex.

So for your example this query will return what you describe:

```
a_metric_total{alabel=~"foo|bar|foobar"} >= 1
```

Please note, that regex selectors for labels are fully anchored (so selector in example is equivalent to `^(foo|bar|foobar)$`) and thus no partial matching is occurring. For regex selector in promql to partially match you need to manually specify that: `.*foo.*|.*bar.*` will match any label containing "foo" or "bar", but `foo|bar` matches only "foo" or "bar", but not "foobar".